# How do I resolve this opencv error?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2410 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.<init>(GUI.java:36)
    at GUI.createWindow(GUI.java:204)
    at GUI.main(GUI.java:221)
```

I am using Eclipse Luna. The weird thing is, I added the opencv_2410.jar to my referenced libraries.

[image]

As for where the error is reached, line36

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

line 204:
        new GUI(imageData, title);
line 221:
        createWindow(imageCopy("filepath"),"Untitled.jpeg");

^Too out the file path for the last one.

Comment: I notice the filenames are a little different:  opencv_java2410 in the error message, but opencv_2410  (without the 'java') in Eclipse.

Comment: Please show us the code where you called initialization for opencv library.

Comment: @Jim Lewis Still giving me the same error